# Determine whether the set of points is achiral

Tags: geometry

I have a set of points in 3D space with given coordinates. Points have labels, thus not all of them are identical in general. How to check whether this set of points achiral or not?

Comment: If the points are labelled, wouldn't even a regular tetrahedron be chiral? If I label the points of a tetrahedron as $1,\,2,\,3,\,4$ and then put it through a reflection swapping points $1$ and $2$, I can show that no rotation achieves the same movement of the labelled vertices.

Comment: I specified more precisely in the question. Points can be differently labeled, but not neccessary. Thus in some boundary case they all can be different, in the other one they all can be identical. Number of points is usually up to 20, number of labels is up to 6.